# New page not opening with the help of pagereference

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have a html input button which calls a javascript function in VF page. After execution of javascript function i want to open a detail page of an account in a new apex window. for that i am writing like below .

```
 <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveImage()"/>
 <apex:actionFunction name="savefn" action="{!saveData}" rerender="">
     <apex:param name="x" value="" assignTo="{!saveImageValue}" />
 </apex:actionFunction>
```

```apex
public void saveData()
{
    String accid,accName;
    for(Account a:[select id,name from Account where id=:account])
    {
        accid=a.Id;
        accName=a.Name;
    }
    //doing my stuff-----
    openDetailPage(account);
}

public PageReference openDetailPage(String acc) 
{ 
   /**Acc contains the id of the account in string format**/
   pageReference ref = new PageReference('/'+acc); 
   ref.setRedirect(true); 
   return ref; 
}
```

I am able to debug out opendetailpage logs but i am unable to open the page. could any one point me where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: where is your `saveImage()` function which needs to be triggered upon the button click?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the function you reference as "SaveData" in the Visualforce page is named "SaveDataData" in the Apex code.

Second thing, "SaveData" is of type void.  It needs to return a page reference.

```
public PageReference saveData()
{
... //skipping unchanged stuff
//doing my stuff-----
return openDetailPage(account);
}
```